# possible to extend SimpleMongoRepository

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-mongodb

My current spring boot mongo configuration looks like following

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(Constants.SCAN_PACKAGE)
@Import(value = MongoAutoConfiguration.class)
public class MongoDatabaseConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ValidatingMongoEventListener validatingMongoEventListener() {
        return new ValidatingMongoEventListener(validator());
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }
}
```

Now i would like to extend the class `SimpleMongoRepository` which seems to be the default implementation of `MongoRepository`. What configuration i have to do so my `CustomMongoRepository` `extends` `SimpleMongoRepository` is picked up instead of `SimpleMongoRepository` which is default shipped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's described in the [Reference Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-behaviour-for-all-repositories)

You basically extend `SimpleMongoRepository` and specify that class in the `@EnableMongoRepositories` annotation as `repositoryBaseClass`.

Comment: * `@EnableMongoRepositories`